# compose.apply(...) is not a function

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I keep getting this error and im not sure what im doing wrong - It looks pretty much exact to the docs except it doesnt work.

```
    import {createStore , combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
    import counterReducer from './ducks/counter'
    
    const reducer = combineReducers({
      counter: counterReducer
    })
    
    let preloadedState
    const preloadedString = localStorage.getItem("prev")
    if(preloadedString){
      preloadedState = JSON.parse(preloadedString)
    }
    
    function thisIsSomeMiddleware(){
      console.log('hey yo');
    }
    const middleware = applyMiddleware(thisIsSomeMiddleware);
    
    const store = createStore(reducer, preloadedState , middleware)
    export default store
```

Can anyone see whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

[applyMiddleware](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware#applymiddlewaremiddleware) needs a [middleware](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware#arguments) so it needs to be a function that looks like this: `store=>next=>action=>next(action)`

Comment: Could you explain? My code was following that example

Comment: @NotaGuruDotCom What example, you failed to provide a link to the example. I provided links to official documentation showing that what is passed to applyMiddleware is a curry that closes over sore and next and finally receives action.